# Is there a Javascript function that simplifies a mixed fraction?

Tags: javascript

If you have a mixed fraction 2 5/4 is there a function in javascript that can simplify a mixed fraction? (The numerator needs to be smaller than the denominator)

I'm new to javascript and my attempt at writing my own code wasn't very successful.

Comment: No, just write it yourself using basic mathematical operations.

Comment: `5/4` is an improper fraction whose value is > 1 (and `2` is an integer > 1). The two cannot make a mixed fraction. If you want numerator < denominator you want something with value < 1.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this library http://hypervolu.me/~erik/fraction.js/. It allows you to get a fraction from a decimal

Otherwise, you can write a simple function that does this work for you.